# Как сделать что бы после точки и по нажатию на enter в EditText / multiline слово писалось с большой буквы?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Как я могу сделать, чтобы после точки и по нажатию на Enter (т.е перевод на новую строку), в `EditText` (multiline) слово писалось с большой буквы?

Пробовал:

```
<EditText
 android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapWords"

        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="top"           
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        />
```

Но в таком случае: "Каждое Слово Пишется С Большой Буквы".

Далее пробовал менять программно:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            if (!(editText.getText().toString()).equals("")) //Если текст не пустой отлавливаем последний символ
            {

                String str = editText.getText().toString();



                char ch = str.charAt(str.length() - 1);

                if (ch != ' ') lastChar = ch;



                if ((lastChar == '.') || ((lastChar == '!')) || ((lastChar == '?')))
                {
                   // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"KEK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS);
                }
             //   else
                  //  editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);

            }


        }



        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        }

    });
```

В итоге получилось так, что он переводит в верхний регистр, но при этом отключает multilite  +  переводит курсор в начало `EditText` и текст начинает вводиться оттуда.

Comment: Попробуйте просто android:inputType="textCapSentences".

Comment: а если android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"

Comment: Спасибо огромное, все было просто android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"